# repeating a jake task using a while loop in coffeescript?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, jake

im trying to run a task 10 times in jake:

```
task 'default', (page) ->
    page = process.env.page
    running = 0
    while running < 10
        ex = jake.createExec(["casperjs test.coffee --page=#{page}"],
            printStdout: true
        )
        ex.run()
        running++
        page++
```

this will run the test 10 times. which is deos fine. however i want it to run in order, so for instance page1 first, then page2, then page3 etc. so first page 1 has to finish before it deos page2. at the momment it runs them in parallel, or asynchronously. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the [Async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library for this kind of thing. Something like:

```
async = require 'async'
pages = for i in [0...10]
  do ->
    j = i
    -> 
      ex = jake.createExec ["casperjs test.coffee --page=#{j}"],
        printStdout: true
      ex.run()
async.series pages
```

I wonder a bit, though, why you need them to run serially.

Comment: thanks it works, what a good fix :). im doing it serially, because the test need to run in order!!